# Java - TimeZone conversion issue with SQL timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, date, calendar, timezone

I am using MySQL database on the Server. My Web application Server is in **US/Chicago** but I want my DateTime values to be saved in **Africa/Lagos** time.

I got part of this code here from Stack Overflow but when I update a record it still shows Chicago time in the database record.
Please what am I doing wrong here?

```
public static boolean saveImageFileName(int id, String fileName) throws SQLException, IOException, IllegalArgumentException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    try(Connection conn = Config.getDatabaseConnection())
    {
        //Create a timezone object based on Africa/Lagos time zone
        SimpleTimeZone timeZone = new SimpleTimeZone(1, "Africa/Lagos");
        //Create a calendar object using the timezone object
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(timeZone);
        //Create a timestamp object using the calendar's date and time
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
        //Create an SQL query String
        String sql = "UPDATE `requests` SET `filename` = ?, `uploaded_date` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
        //Create a prepared statement object from database connection
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //Set prepared statement parameters
        pst.setString(1, fileName);
        pst.setTimestamp(2, timestamp, calendar); //Set TimeStamp and Calendar
        pst.setInt(3, id);
        //Update the record
        int update = pst.executeUpdate();
        //return update result
        return update == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
pst.setObject( 2 , Instant.now() ) ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( 2 , Instant.class ) ;  // Stored moment in UTC.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Lagos" ) ) ;   // Adjust from UTC to time zone. Same moment, same point on timeline, but different wall-clock time.
```

## Do *not* rely on `toString`

Apparently you are being confused by the output of the legacy date-time classes’ `toString` method. Among the many poor design decisions in those old classes was the anti-feature of applying the JVM’s current time zone while generating a String to textually represent the value of that date-time object. This creates the confusing illusion that the object has a time zone when it does not.

So you cannot use `toString` on those old classes as it does not faithfully represent the true value.

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Lagos" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zdt ) ;
```

But the time zone is irrelevant here as a `java.sql.Timestamp` is always in UTC. The equivalent is a `Instant` in java.time. You can extract an `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime` or get the current moment in UTC as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjusting from a time zone to UTC.
```

Or…

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, you can work directly with java.time types and forsake the legacy java.sql types. Call `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

If your JDBC has not yet been updated for java.time, convert to a `java.sql.Timestamp` using new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant ) ;
```

Going the other way, you can adjust an `Instant` into a particular time zone when you want to see that same moment through the lens of a particular region’s wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )  // Or call: ts.toInstant()
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

As for generating String objects to represent textually the value of these java.time objects, you *can* rely on calling the `toString` methods. The java.time classes by default use the sensible practical formats defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `Calendar` object with TimeZone in `setTimeZone` method, as mentioned in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29) javadoc, try this:

```
pst.setTimestamp(2, timestamp, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Lagos")));
```

Comment: It's still showing Chicago Time 2017-06-04 08:31:35 instead of 2017-06-04 14:31:35